# Hadoop WikipediaPageInputFormat

Tags: hadoop

I'm working on an assignment and learning to work with Hadoop. I'm trying to work with Wikipedia pages but keep getting an error when I try to set the input format. Here is my code:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Set;

import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileOutputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobConf;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapReduceBase;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Mapper;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.OutputCollector;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Reducer;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Reporter;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextOutputFormat;

import edu.umd.cloud9.collection.wikipedia.WikipediaPage;
import edu.umd.cloud9.collection.wikipedia.WikipediaPageInputFormat;



public class InvertedIndex {

    public static class InvertedIndexMapper extends MapReduceBase
    implements Mapper<LongWritable, WikipediaPage, Text, Text> {

    private Text title = new Text();
    private Text word = new Text();

        public void map(LongWritable key, WikipediaPage value,
                OutputCollector<Text, Text> output, Reporter report)
                throws IOException {

            String articleTitle = value.getTitle();
            title.set(articleTitle);

            String content = value.getContent();
            String[] words = content.split(" ");

            for (String s : words) {
                word.set(s);
                output.collect(word, title);
            }   
        }
    }

    public static class InvertedIndexReducer extends MapReduceBase
        implements Reducer<Text, Text, Text, Text> {

        public void reduce (Text key, Iterator<Text> values,
                OutputCollector<Text, Text> output, Reporter report)
                throws IOException {

            Set<String> articlesSet = new HashSet<String>();
            Text articleNames = new Text();

            while (values.hasNext()) {
                articlesSet.add(values.toString());
            }

            String names = "";

            for (String s : articlesSet) {
                names += s + ", ";
            }

            articleNames.set(names);

            output.collect(key, articleNames);

        }
    }

    public static void main (String[] args) throws Exception {
        JobConf conf = new JobConf(InvertedIndex.class);
        conf.setJobName("InvertedIndex");

        conf.setInputFormat(WikipediaPageInputFormat.class);
        conf.setOutputFormat(TextOutputFormat.class);

        conf.setMapperClass(InvertedIndexMapper.class);
        conf.setReducerClass(InvertedIndexReducer.class);
        conf.setMapOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
        conf.setMapOutputValueClass(Text.class);
        conf.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
        conf.setOutputValueClass(Text.class);

        FileInputFormat.setInputPaths(conf, new Path(args[0]));
        FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(conf, new Path(args[1]));

        long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        JobClient.runJob(conf);
        System.out.println("Job finished in :" + (System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime) / 1000 + " seconds");
    }
}
```

I'm using eclipse and get the following error at the line conf.setInputFormat(WikipediaPageInputFormat.class);

> The method setInputFormat (Class ? extends InputFormat ) in the type JobConf is not applicable for the arguments ( Class WikipediaPageInputFormat)

When I try to compile I get the following error:

> InvertedIndex.java:81: cannot find symbol
>
> symbol  : method setInputFormatClass(java.lang.Class edu.umd.cloud9.collection.wikipedia.WikipediaPageInputFormat )
>
> location: class org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobConf
>                  conf.setInputFormatClass(WikipediaPageInputFormat.class);

I would appreciate any help or suggestions on how to correct this if someone has experienced it before.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

WikipediaPageInputFormat is a class for new Hadoop API (org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.*), so you should use Job class instead of JobConf to configure your job.
For convenience Cloud9 also has WikipediaPageInputFormatOld for the old API.